# add all numbers in a element with same class

Tags: javascript

i am trying to add all numbers of elements with same class.
like this :-

`<span class="total"> 4</span>`
`<span class="total"> 8</span>`
`<span class="total"> 5</span>`
`<span class="total"> 3</span>`
`<span class="total"> 9</span>`
`<span class="total"> 12</span>`
`<span class="total"> 34</span>`
`<span class="total"> 22</span>`

answer to be show in `<p id="answer"></p>`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: try to use for loop

Comment: Show what you've tried. Add it to your question. Ideally, create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
let total = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('.total').forEach(span=>{
    total += ~~span.textContent;
});
document.querySelector('#answer').textContent = total;
```